# Question regarding a ring homomorphism of polynomials with coefficients in a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I have a map $\sigma_a:K[x]\to K[x]$, where $K$ is a field, defined by $g(x)\mapsto g(x+a)$. I'd like to show that this ring homomorphism is in fact an isomorphism. I can easily see the map is surjective; however, I can't seem to be able to show that it is injective. One approach I have taken is given $g(x+a)=g(x+y)$, attempting to show that $x=y$; however, I can only show that $g(x)=g(y)$, and I immediately think of situations like $x^2+1=y^2+1$, where $x$ can equal $1$, while $y$ equals $-1$. Another approach I have considered is showing that the kernel is trivial; however, again I am stuck as I'm not sure what the identity is in this scenario.

I'd like to ask for any help with both approaches as I am sure they will both be informative.

For more context, the purpose of this ring homomorphism is in proving that the polynomial $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\dots+x+1$, where $p$ is a prime number, is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: Is not it enough that $\sigma_a$ has an inverse, i.e. $\sigma_{-a}$ ?

Comment: Injective says if $f(x+a)=g(x+a)$ for some polynomials $f,g$, then $f=g$.

Comment: @blamocur what is the theory on this? I know for two sets, say $A$ and $B$, if there exists injective maps from $A$ to $B$, and from $B$ to $A$, then the two sets have the same cardinality. Is what you're mentioning somewhat similar, and would the inverse also not need to be injective?

Comment: @Wuestenfux in this case, how would I prove surjectivity? Because what you've said implies the method I used is not correct.

Comment: @Seth: non-injective homomorphism would not have an inverse. More formally: if $\forall x\in K: f(x+a) = g(x+a)$ then replacing $u=x+a$ we have $\forall u\in: f(u)=g(u)$ (since $x\rightarrow x+a$ is a one-to-one map). But this implies $f=g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\sigma_a\circ\sigma_{-a} = id = \sigma_{-a}\circ\sigma_a$ and so $\sigma_a$ is bijective.